# Unable to launch Apache Flink 1.7 on Google Cloud Dataproc

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink, google-cloud-dataproc

I launched a Dataproc cluster with Hadoop 2.9.2, downloaded Flink 1.7.2  and tried launching it using the following command:

```
./bin/yarn-session.sh  -n 2
```

This failed with the following error message:

```
Setting HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf because no HADOOP_CONF_DIR was set.
2019-02-15 12:56:05,679 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.address, localhost
2019-02-15 12:56:05,680 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.rpc.port, 6123
2019-02-15 12:56:05,681 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: jobmanager.heap.size, 1024m
2019-02-15 12:56:05,681 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.heap.size, 1024m
2019-02-15 12:56:05,681 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots, 1
2019-02-15 12:56:05,681 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: parallelism.default, 1
2019-02-15 12:56:05,682 INFO  org.apache.flink.configuration.GlobalConfiguration            - Loading configuration property: rest.port, 8081
2019-02-15 12:56:06,241 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader                       - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2019-02-15 12:56:06,323 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.security.modules.HadoopModule        - Hadoop user set to robert (auth:SIMPLE)
2019-02-15 12:56:06,534 ERROR org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - Error while running the Flink Yarn session.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.timeline.TimelineUtils.<clinit>(TimelineUtils.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.serviceInit(YarnClientImpl.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli.getClusterDescriptor(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:984)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli.createDescriptor(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:273)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli.createClusterDescriptor(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:451)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli.run(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:588)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli.lambda$main$2(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:810)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli.main(FlinkYarnSessionCli.java:810)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 49 more
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the best way to install Flink would be to use the [initialization action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/flink) which installs via apt-get from Dataproc's distro to get the version of Flink that has been cross-compiled and tested against the given Dataproc version. In that case, you shouldn't need to modify any environment variables for it to work.

If you do want to use a specific version of Flink with a Dataproc version which doesn't provide that version of Flink in the distro, indeed you may need to install from a download of Flink like you have done. You can also look at one of the [earlier versions of the initialization action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/commit/a5aaae617d0ec34fc25f926846d64278d405928d#diff-68c03a76152dc53fdd2c7c7ab07f2721) when it installed Flink from a tarball to see the kinds of configuration that may have been necessary. For example, based on that earlier init action you may also want to export `HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf`.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I needed to export the following variable:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath`
```

Comment: I got this answer from here: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-dev/201808.mbox/%3CCAC2R295o5t8q5G4Bk==ijPFwksmWZWhMXKN3jwGTWdJCdHeihQ@mail.gmail.com%3E